# How to convert ContentValues[] to ContentValues

Tags: android, android-asynctask

here i am using AsyncTask for working with database, due to my Cursor.requery needs, i am sending a ContentValue to the Async like this:

```
 public void todisplay(String username,String realname,String image1,String 
 image2,String email){
   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(5);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_USERNAME, username);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_REALNAME, realname);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_IMAGE1, image1);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_IMAGE2, image2);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_EMAIL, email);

   AsyncAdd async = new AsyncAdd();
   async.execute(cv);


  public class AsyncAdd extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, String ,String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(ContentValues... params) {

       mDb.insert(MyDbHelperContacts.TABLE_NAME, null, params);
       mCursor.requery();


       return null;
}
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
super.onPostExecute(result);
```

}

but the (ContentValues...params) is turning my ContentValues into ContentValues[], which the insert doesnt accept, could you guys give me a tip how can i convert back from ContentValues[] to ContentValues ? thanks alot

Comment: wait a second can i just use params[0] in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one item, you can do this:

```
mDb.insert(MyDbHelperContacts.TABLE_NAME, null, params[0]);
```

Comment: yes man just went through my mind, thanks alot :D i will accept the answer as soon as i can :D

Comment: also may i ask how can i input an int into the async task?

Comment: @user3694470 I presume you refer to a _different_ AsyncTask? Define it as `AsyncTask<Integer, ...>`

Comment: nah dude Integer is different from int, nvm figgured this out too :)